# Как из span-ов сделать стрелку?

Tags: html, css

```
<div>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Из этого нужно сделать стрелку: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно из 3 span-ов

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Достаточно одного:

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 2px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: gray;
}

span:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent gray;
  border-width: 6px 0 6px 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  left: 100%;
  top: -5px;
}
```

```html
<span>
```

Comment: А если задать исходному span какой-нибудь `font-size: 30px;` а все остальные размеры прописать в единицах `em`, легче будет при необходимости менять размеры стрелок, сменой одного числа font-size)

Comment: можно даже в vw задать, тогда будет строго соответствовать габаритам экрана. Но пусть автор тоже приложит усилия ;)